# Is there a way to check if a generic parameter (HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<?>>) is of a certian type?

Tags: java, generics, parameters, hashmap, type-erasure

I have a function that uses a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<CustomObject1>> map` as a parameter. However, now functionality has been expanded and I need to call this function with a different HashMap that contains `ArrayList<CustomObject2>>`.

I've looked into generics and tried passing in `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<? extends CustomObjectBase>> map` but I will need to know what is actually passed in so I can respond accordingly. Making another function did not work due to type erasure. I've also tried using `java instanceof` but that does not work either.

Any advice on how this could be solved? Thank you!

Comment: Make a function with a different name.

Comment: how did you try using `instanceof`?

Answer (score 2):

I've spent hours trying this on my own before, and it was a fruitless endeavor. It is generally preferred to instead pass the class as a parameter, like so:

```
public void <T> handle(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<T>> map, Class<T> clazz)
{
    // do whatever you need to, based on 
}
```

Then, you'll call it like so:

```
var map1 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<CustomObject1>>();
// map1 populate...
var map2 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<CustomObject2>>();
// map1 populate...
var h = new Handler();
h.handle(map1, CustomObject1.class);
h.handle(map2, CustomObject2.class);
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it if it is hard to refactor the design. Otherwise, it is better to change the design so that class T implements a different functionality you need or to have another class that implements functionality for class T. For example if you need a different way to compare values depending on a class then you can also pass Comparator<T> along the ArrayList<T>.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` is your friend:

```
if (map instanceof CustomObject1) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Also, you can use method overloading as well. You have method1 that you are talking about, yet you need to do some differentiation between the types. The custom logic that you need for can be delegated to method2 and you can implement different overloads if they are different.

Also, `map.get(0).getClass().getName()` can come in handy here if your array list is not empty, of course.